# Fix Overlapping Partitions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, arch-linux, gparted

Today I went to resize one of my drivers partitions as I am currently switching from Ubuntu to ArchLinux as my main OS.
However when I go into Gparted I get the error "Cant have overlapping partitions".
Checking Fdisk gives the below resolt:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   318586879   159190016    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       770101248   976773167   103335960   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       318588926   770103295   225757185    5  Extended
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       318588928   770101247   225756160   83  Linux
```

Looks like sda4 is overlapping with sda3.
I know my partitions are a big of a mess, one of the reason I am moving from Ubuntu so I can remove the sda4 and 5 leaving just Windows (sad1+2) and arch linux (sda 3).

So I guess my question is how to fix this overlapping. if possible by shirking sda4/5 so there is no longer a over lap?

I would prefer to keep retain my data but everything is backed up so if there realy is no other option I could to a complete clean install... but why I am here is to see if there is anything way first.

Thank you and if you need any more info let me know!

Comment: If two partitions overlap, then very likely you don't have any data to keep anymore, since writing to sda5 will corrupt data in sda3 and vice versa.

Comment: Well this is the odd thing, if you look the partitions /sda5 and sda3 do not over lap its the extended partition that does, and the bit that is over lapping isnt actually being used in sda4. I still have access to all the date on both sda 3 and 5 and its quite possible its been like this for at least a week since I isntall arch to sda 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) program. It *should* fix the problem automatically. I recommend launching it on the disk and using FixParts' `p` option to view your partition table. Note that FixParts doesn't show extended partitions at all, so don't worry when you don't see your `/dev/sda4`. If you see all the other partitions, though, and if none of them is listed as `omitted` in the `Status` column, go ahead and type `w` to save the repaired partition table.